# Angularjs routeProvider and Asp.net 5 Razor

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I know that there are a lot of duplicates of this topic and I've found some articles which explain how to implement **angularjs** routeProvider with **.cshtml**, but it didn't help me. Here, in stackoverflow, there were some similar problems that I've looked at but it didn't help me either. Could you help me please.

Here is my angular module:

```
QuizApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/index', {
                templateUrl: '/home/index',
                controller: 'QuizController' //new
            }).
            when('/quiz', {
                templateUrl: '/home/quiz',
                controller: 'QuizController' //new
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/index'
            });
    }]);
```

If i join localhost:port/home/quiz - it works

If i join localhost:port/#/quiz - it is just show me default page (index).

ps. Guys, if you need some more information, just tell me please.

**UPDATE 2.**
Add a bit more code witch comments //new

Also I've found one defect that when i'm adding to my page:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

Page just freeze, and I can't make anything on it.

Comment: localhost:port/#!/quiz

Comment: @Miha2255 Also not working

Comment: You're mixing angular routing and MVC routing. Request to /home/quiz is routed by MVC to HomeController, method Quiz. Request to /#/quiz is (ALSO) routed by MVC to /Home/Index (default route). No Angular routes are taking place here from what I can tell.

Comment: @AndersonMatos Could you please give me a suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: Do you want to use MVC routing, or would you be happy for angular just manage the routing?

Comment: @BlakeMumford I would be happy if angular will manage the routing :)